# Order of color changes in 3D plots

Tags: plotting, color

I am plotting 3D graphs wherein I have an equation with a variable parameter $m$ and I have to plot the graphs by taking 6 different values of the variable parameter. I am using color function `TemperatureMap` to show the different regions of the 3D plot. For $m=0$, I plot this graph and the colors on the graph are like this from bottom to top: navy blue, blue, red. Next I plot it for $m=1$, my colors become (from bottom to top) blue, very light blue, red. Every time I plot with a different value of $m$, the order of colors changes or get shifted. I don't have any other problem with it except that the color of the graph at $(q,p)=(0,0)$ changes everytime which causes ambiguity. How can I keep the colors constant everytime? Thank you.

```
\[Gamma] = q + I*p; 
z = 1; 
\[Theta] = Pi/4; 

m = 0; 
a0 = Sum[((1/(j!*l!))*Binomial[m, j]*Binomial[m, l]*
       Conjugate[z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]]]^j*
              (-2*\[Gamma] + z*Cos[\[Theta]])^
        j*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])^l*
              
       HypergeometricU[-l, 
        1 + j - l, (-2*\[Gamma] + 
           z*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + 
                     Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])]*(z*Sin[\[Theta]]*
          Tan[\[Theta]])^l)/
           ((-2*\[Gamma] + z*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + 
          Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]))^l, {j, 0, m}, 
         {l, 0, m}]/(E^(2*Abs[\[Gamma] - z*Cos[\[Theta]]]^2)*
          (Pi*Sum[((1/(k!*l!))*(-1)^k*Binomial[m, k]*Binomial[m, l]*
                    
           Conjugate[z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]]]^
            l*((-z)*Cos[\[Theta]])^l*(Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])^k*
                    
           HypergeometricU[-k, 
            1 - k + l, (-z)*Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]^2]*
                    (z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]])^k)/((-z)*
            Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^k, {l, 0, m}, 
               {k, 0, m}])); 

p0 = Plot3D[a0 // Chop, {q, -4, 4}, {p, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]

m = 1;

a1 = Sum[((1/(j!*l!))*Binomial[m, j]*Binomial[m, l]*
        Conjugate[z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]]]^
         j*(-2*\[Gamma] + z*Cos[\[Theta]])^
         j*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])^l*
               
        HypergeometricU[-l, 
         1 + j - l, (-2*\[Gamma] + 
            z*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + 
            Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])]*(z*Sin[\[Theta]]*
           Tan[\[Theta]])^l)/
            ((-2*\[Gamma] + 
           z*Cos[\[Theta]])*(-2*Conjugate[\[Gamma]] + 
           Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]))^l, {j, 0, m}, {l, 0, m}]/
    E^(2*Abs[\[Gamma] - z*Cos[\[Theta]]]^2)/
      (Pi*
     Sum[((1/(k!*l!))*(-1)^k*Binomial[m, k]*Binomial[m, l]*
         Conjugate[z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]]]^
          l*((-z)*Cos[\[Theta]])^l*(Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]])^k*
                
         HypergeometricU[-k, 
          1 - k + l, (-z)*Conjugate[z]*
           Cos[\[Theta]]^2]*(z*Sin[\[Theta]]*Tan[\[Theta]])^k)/((-z)*
          Conjugate[z]*Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^k, {l, 0, m}, {k, 0, m}]);



p1 = Plot3D[a1 // Chop, {q, -4, 4}, {p, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]
```

Comment: Please post an example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following changes in the definitions for `p0` and `p1`:

```
p0 = Plot3D[a0 // Chop, {q, -4, 4}, {p, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
      Rescale[#3, {0.0, 0.3}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]

p1 = Plot3D[a1 // Chop, {q, -4, 4}, {p, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
      Rescale[#3, {0.0, 0.3}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]


GraphicsRow[{p0, p1}]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

For corresponding density plots:

```
p3 = DensityPlot[a0 // Chop, {q, -4, 4}, {p, -4, 4}
   , PlotRange -> All
   , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
       Rescale[#1, {0, 0.3}]] &)
   , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   , PlotPoints -> 50
   ];

p4 = DensityPlot[a1 // Chop, {q, -4, 4}, {p, -4, 4}
   , PlotRange -> All
   , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
       Rescale[#1, {0, 0.3}]] &)
   , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   , PlotPoints -> 50
   ];

GraphicsRow[{p3, p4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the problem. However, if I density plot using the same ColorFunction command which you used, it does not execute. I get the error "Slot number 3 in ColorData cannot be filled". Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Anaya I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much